# Side-by-side scrolling in Safari 6 using flexbox

Tags: html, css, safari, scroll, flexbox

I'm trying to build two side-by-side scrollable panels with flexbox:

**HTML:**

```
<div class"scrollable"></div>
<div class"scrollable"></div>
```

**SASS**

```
@import "flex"

*
  padding: 0
  margin: 0

html
  height: 100%

body
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  +flexbox()

.scrollable
  overflow-y: auto
  min-height: 0
  +flex-grow(1)
```

It's working perfectly in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari 6 the scrollbars are missing. Any ideas to why this is?

I'm using this mixin for flexbox which should have support for Safari's flexbox implementation: https://github.com/mastastealth/sass-flex-mixin/blob/master/flex.scss

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox 2009 is not just a version of the Flexbox specification with different names and a few less properties.  There are many subtle things that do not translate between the two, plus every implementation of the 2009 Flexbox specification is buggy.

For whatever reason, setting the height to 100%, rather than using a min-height of 0, helps Safari figure out that it needs to add scroll bars (and doesn't appear to have a negative impact on other browsers).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/4plssmrq

```
/* line 5, ../sass/rar.sass */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* line 9, ../sass/rar.sass */
html {
  height: 100%;
}

/* line 12, ../sass/rar.sass */
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

/* line 17, ../sass/rar.sass */
.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer cimmanon. The problem is that I don't know the height of the scrollable containers – they need to be able to nest within another flexbox element.

Comment: You can't use height of 100%?  Can you provide markup/styles for the surrounding elements?

Comment: I've made an implementation of the surrounding elements here: http://codepen.io/asnoba/full/yqekb

Comment: Is there a reason you have so many flex containers?  You should only need the one on `#main` and maybe `#wrapper` if your header has an unknown height.

Comment: Otherwise I couldn't get the scrollbars to show, but I might have been missing something?